# Auto-negotiation Disable Issue

Tags: communication, ethernet, network

How can I set the ethernet speed ?

Comment: Why not reveal the PHY type and add a link to the manual with register map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* deactive autonegotiation for twisted-pair Ethernet. Doing so removes the link partner's ability to detect duplex mode, causing it to fall back to half duplex. This in turn can very easily cause a duplex mismatch, resulting in extremely high collision / FCS error counts and very poor performance. Additionally, not all link partners might be able to successfully link with your device.

Instead, limit your switch's autonegotiation advertisement to 10BASE-T only. From what I can find in the datasheet, clear bits 7-8 in register 0x04 to remove 100BASE-TX in either duplex mode.

Comment: After your comment I search lots of things about the auto-negation.Making disable would be really pointless. I did successfully set 10Mbs  thank you very much